# Validation of user input not working

Tags: c++

I was wondering if anyone can help, I have the code below and I would like to add validation to make sure that the user can't enter a number less than 1 or more than 9 however I can not get it to work, can anyone help thanks.

I have tried putting

```
if(x >=1 && x <= 9)
```

statement around the content of the bellow code but that does not work.

```
for(int x = 0;x < 9; x++)
```

Code I have:

```
void interactiveSudokuFill(int grid1[9][9]){

for(int y=0;y<9;y++){
 for(int x=0;x<9;x++){
    string theString;
    cout<<"Write the value to place in Sudoku["<<y<<"]["<<x<<"] :"<<endl;
    std::getline(cin,theString);
    int nr=atoi(theString.c_str());
    grid1[y][x]=nr;
    system("cls");

}

}
}
```

Comment: It might be because you try to validate `x` when you should validate `nr`?

Comment: You used if(nr >=1 && nr <= 9) and what is the meaning of "that does not work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `x` is not the value that the user is entering. You should be checking `nr`:

```
if(nr >= 1 && nr <= 9) {
  grid1[y][x] = nr;
}
```

Typically, extraction of an `int` from `std::cin` is done like this:

```
int nr;
std::cin >> nr;
```

If you want to keep asking the user for a new value until they enter one that is both an integer and a correct integer:

```
int nr = 0;
do {
  std::cin >> nr;
  std::cin.clear();
} while(nr < 1 || nr > 9);
grid[y][x] = nr;
```

Comment: I would recomment a do while loop here instead of if

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I suppose that depends on what they want to achieve. If the `if` fails, the grid element will be left unchanged. Maybe that's what they want.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go and check it, I always make mistakes like this :(

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I have one more question that maybe you could help with, When I enter say 12 it displays the error message but still moves on to ask the user to fill in the next element, is there a way to stay on the same element until a value is accepted?

Comment: @Thomas: That was exactly the meaning of my comment. You use a do-while loop, as such: `do {PromtInput; GetInput; } while(InputIsINVALID);`

Comment: @Thomas Try my edit. It will also continue to work if they enter something that is not an integer.

Comment: @sftrabbit  Thanks, How do I store the value in the array thought? I am really new to all this std::cin stuff, I have tried putting grid[y][x] = nr after the 2 statements in the do loop but That gives me an error, is that not the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void interactiveSudokuFill(int grid1[9][9]){

for(int y=0;y<9;y++){
 for(int x=0;x<9;x++){
string theString;
cout<<"Write the value to place in Sudoku["<<y<<"]["<<x<<"] :"<<endl;
std::getline(cin,theString);
int nr=atoi(theString.c_str());
if(nr>=1 && nr<=9){
     grid1[y][x]=nr;
}
else{
 cout<<"Invalid number."<<endl;
 x--;
}
system("cls");

}

}
}

x-- and surely aren't the most correct way of doing things but it works...
```

Comment: What is `x--, y--` supposed to achieve? If you want the user to re-enter the number, you should use an extra do-while loop instead of trying to go to the previous cell, which you did incorrectly by the way (you will be forced to re-enter an entire row, not to mention it would crash if you were in the first row to begin with).

Comment: it should be only x--. So the user gets prompted for the same number instead of the next one. You surely could do it with an inner loop I know... but this works to.

Comment: _any_ explanations to the fish you just posted?